# How to call a function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, output

so i tried making 2 functions and want to display both outputs and im new to C++
how do i fix this issue?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace first{
    int x = 1;
}
namespace second{
    int x = 2;
}
int main() {

using namespace first;


int x = 0;


std::cout << x << '\n';
std::cout << first::x << '\n';
std::cout << second::x << '\n';

return 0;
}

int lol() {

using namespace std;
using std::cout;

string lolipop = "hello world";

cout << lolipop << '\n';

return 0;

}
```

i want to display both outputs including hello world and the variables, variable are getting displayed in the output but not the second function the lol one.

Comment: You're not calling the `lol` function.

Comment: ok how do i do it? im new to this.

Comment: Please decide on a learning source for your further progress. Select any book or course to follow. Writing random code and then hoping that it will achieve your goal is not a reliable way. Trying and then asking here kind of works, but it is an inefficient use of your time in the long run.

Comment: Simply, the program starts at the top of main, then runs through every line until the end of main. Every function needs to be called except main. So, right before you return 0 in main, you could add `lol();` and it would call the function and run its logic before the main ends and the program exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `lol()`.

Example:

```
int lol(); // forward declaration

int main() {
    using namespace first;

    int x = 0;

    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::cout << first::x << '\n';
    std::cout << second::x << '\n';
    
    lol();                             // calling lol

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `lol` function from `main`.